# Prisma - Update previously created models, which are already saved in the database

Tags: database, mongodb, prisma

Let's say I had a model called User which had some fields. Now, if I update the model and add a field called Votes, how do I update all the previously created models? This is a small-scale example, but how do I do the same on a large scale, i.e. after updating many models with both required and optional fields?

PS: `prisma migrate` doesn't work as I am using MongoDB as the provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use MongoDB with Prisma, you operate under a schemaless model, which allows you to alter the structure of your documents without having to modify a centralized schema.

Considering this example:

```
model User {
  id    String @id @default(dbgenerated()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name  String
  email String @unique
}
```

Now, assume you want to add a new field called `votes`. You can simply modify your Prisma schema like so:

```
model User {
  id    String @id @default(dbgenerated()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name  String
  email String @unique
  votes Int?
}
```

Notice that `votes` is optional (noted by the `?`). When you create new `User` documents, you can include the `votes` field, and when you update `User` documents, you can also update the `votes` field. However, for existing `User` documents that were created before you added the `votes` field, MongoDB won't automatically add this field. Those documents simply won't have the `votes` field until you manually update them to include it.

To add the `votes` field to all existing `User` documents, you can write a script that uses Prisma's `updateMany` function. Here's an example script that sets `votes` to `0` for all `User` documents:

```js
await prisma.user.updateMany({
  data: {
    votes: 0,
  },
});
```

For larger, more complex updates involving many models with both required and optional fields, you'd have to carefully write scripts like the one above that update your documents as needed.